# Update marker in Gmaps + Jupyter using widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm studying gmaps and I'm trying refresh gmap marker using widgets.button, but I cannot refresh map when I click in button.
Maybe is a simple question, but I'm trying it for hours and can't solve.
Follow my code.

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key='')


class AcledExplorer(object):
    """
    Jupyter widget for exploring the ACLED dataset.

    The user uses the slider to choose a year. This renders
    a heatmap of civilian victims in that year.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.marker_locations = [(None, None)]
        self._slider = None
        self._slider2 = None
        title_widget = widgets.HTML(
            '<h3>MY TEST, my test</h3>'
            '<h4>test1 <a href="https://www.test.com/">ACLED project</a></h4>'
        )

        map_figure = self._render_map(-15.7934036, -47.8823172)
        control = self._render_control()
        self._container = widgets.VBox([title_widget, control, map_figure])

    def render(self):
        display(self._container)

    def on_button_clicked(self, b):
        latitude = self.FloatSlider1.value
        longitude = self.FloatSlider2.value
        print("Button clicked.")
        self.markers = gmaps.marker_layer([(latitude, longitude)])
        return self._container

    def _render_control(self):

        """ Render the widgets """

        self.FloatSlider1 = widgets.FloatSlider(
        value=-15.8,
        min=-34,
        max=4.5,
        step=0.2,
        description='Latitude:',
        disabled=False,
        continuous_update=False,
        orientation='horizontal',
        readout=True,
        readout_format='.1f',
    )
        self.FloatSlider2 = widgets.FloatSlider(
        value=-47.9,
        min=-74,
        max=-33,
        step=0.2,
        description='Longitude:',
        disabled=False,
        continuous_update=False,
        orientation='horizontal',
        readout=True,
        readout_format='.1f',
    )
        self.button = widgets.Button(
            description="Plot!"
        )

        self.button.on_click(self.on_button_clicked)

        controls = widgets.VBox(
        [self.FloatSlider1, self.FloatSlider2, self.button])
        return controls

    def _render_map(self, latitude, longitude):
        """ Render the initial map """
        self.marker_locations = [(latitude, longitude)]
        brasilia_coordinates = (-15.7934036, -47.8823172)

        fig = gmaps.figure(center=brasilia_coordinates, zoom_level=3)
        self.markers = gmaps.marker_layer(self.marker_locations)
        fig.add_layer(self.markers)
        return fig


AcledExplorer().render()
```

I start creating widgets, after I link values from Sliders to button. I need refresh marker position when click in button.

In function on_button_click I can view that news values of latitude and longitude are being getting from slider bar, so I'm update self.marker, maybe my mistake stay here.

[image: Result of code image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem with your code

In `on_button_click`, you are not actually updating the marker layer. You currently write:

```py
self.markers = gmaps.marker_layer([(latitude, longitude)])
```

but that just sets the `markers` attribute of your class. What you actually want to do is mutate the set of markers in your marker layer. The simplest change you can make is to change that line to:

```py
self.markers.markers = [gmaps.Marker(location=(latitude, longitude))]
```

This mutates the `markers` attribute of your marker layer — basically the list of markers. Every time you press plot, it destroys the marker on the map and replaces it with a new one at an updated location.

## Improving your solution

Using the high-level factory methods like `marker_layer` can obscure how *jupyter-gmaps* uses widgets internally. To make it somewhat more understandable, let's introduce a `_create_marker()` method that creates a `gmaps.Marker` object:

```py
def _create_marker(self, latitude, longitude):
    return gmaps.Marker(location=(latitude, longitude))
```

We can now use this in the initial render:

```py
def _render_map(self, latitude, longitude):
    """ Render the initial map """
    brasilia_coordinates = (-15.7934036, -47.8823172)

    fig = gmaps.figure(center=brasilia_coordinates, zoom_level=3)
    self.marker_layer = gmaps.Markers()
    initial_marker = self._create_marker(latitude, longitude)
    self.marker_layer.markers = [initial_marker]  # set the first marker
    fig.add_layer(self.marker_layer)
    return fig
```

Note that I have renamed `self.markers` to `self.marker_layer` to make it clear it's a layer.

Finally, the update code is now:

```py
def on_button_clicked(self, _):
    latitude = self.FloatSlider1.value
    longitude = self.FloatSlider2.value

    # look how closely the following two lines match the construction code
    new_marker = self._create_marker(latitude, longitude)
    self.marker_layer.markers = [new_marker]
```

Comment: Hi Pascal, tnx very much for your fast help.
I'm trying yet, but I cannot solve my problem.
Using your suggestion I cannot run script because:
         self.marker_layer = gmaps.Markers()

gmaps.Markers() are asking for location Parameters. It is curious because in documentation to Markers() location isn't required.
The erro is:
The 'markers' trait of a Markers instance must be of length 1 <= L <= 9223372036854775807, but a value of [] was specified.

Comment: Apologies -- I'd made a typo in the `_render_map` method. I edited that. Let me know if you have any issues.

I didn't have to make changes to the `gmaps.Markers` call at all. What version of `gmaps` are you using? (`gmaps.__version__`)

Comment: Sorry Pascal, maybe my problem is my environment. I can't run line - `self.marker_layer = gmaps.Markers()`. Part of error: 
`...---> 18 map_figure = self._render_map(-15.7934036, -47.8823172)
 
---> 79         self.marker_layer = gmaps.Markers()

TraitError: The 'markers' trait of a Markers instance must be of length 1 <= L <= 9223372036854775807, but a value of [] was specified.`

I'm running on gmaps.__version__ = 0.8.2
Mac OS Mojave - Jupyter notebook 5.7.4

I tried do a minimal script using example in page 49 of documentation but no working too, in this case, no refresh positions

Comment: We made significant changes to the marker layer in a recent version. I've done all my testing in 0.8.4. I'd definitely recommend upgrading.

Comment: Ahhh Ok. Tonight ( in Brazil =] ) I will upgrade gmaps version and try again. I come back later with news !